# If $\gcd(7,abc)=1$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2$, prove that $7$ divides $a^2-b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The only information I have on this problem is that for $a^2+b^2=c^2$ that
$$
a = st, b = \frac{s^2-t^2}{2}, c = \frac{s^2+t^2}{2}
$$
and that $\gcd(7,abc)=1$ gives $7x + abcy = 1$

I have no idea how to proceed, so any help welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what is given, $a,b,c$ are not multiples of $7$. From $(\pm1)^2\equiv 1\pmod 7$, $(\pm2)^2\equiv 4\pmod 7$, $(\pm3)^2\equiv 2\pmod 7$., we see that the only few values for $a^2,b^2,c^2\pmod7$ are possible and the only combinations leading to $a^2+b^2=c^2$ are $1+1\equiv 2$ and $2+2\equiv4$ and $4+4\equiv1$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$x\equiv\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\implies x^2\equiv1,4,2\pmod7$$

So, if $a^2\equiv1,b^2$ must be $\equiv1\pmod7$ and so on

Comment: how do you get that x is equivalent to either plus/minus 1, 2, or 3? why can't it be 4 5 or 6?

Comment: @JohnL., $$4=7-3\equiv-3$$ etc.